# Oracle SQL: Query the email that appear in different country

Tags: sql, oracle11g

My customer table below:

```
Ctry    Email
-------------
US    abc@test.com
JP    aaa@test.com
GB    abc@test.com
```

I am not able to filter out the email that appear in multiple country.
**My expected outcome is:**

```
US    abc@test.com
GB    abc@test.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If the countries are not duplicate, following query works fine.

```
SELECT A.CTRY, X.EMAIL
FROM MY_TABLE A,
    (SELECT EMAIL
        FROM MY_TABLE
        GROUP BY EMAIL HAVING COUNT(EMAIL)<>1) X
WHERE A.EMAIL=X.EMAIL;
```

[Run on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fb5587/5)

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I need a scenario where distinct email appear in duplicate country.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. :)

```
select country, email
from
(select country, email, count(country) over (partition by email) dup_count
from cntry_email) sub
where sub.dup_count > 1
```

Here's the link to help you understand more over and partition by 
http://www.midnightdba.com/Jen/2010/10/tip-over-and-partition-by/

Hope it helps. :)
Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for letting me know. Glad I could help. :)